# IOwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie") with Steam auth is randomly null after a couple of succuessful authentications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, steam

I've been trying to implement Steam authentication in my ASP.Net web app (ASP.Net Framework 4.8, MVC 5) using Owin and its Steam auth provider (Owin.Security.Providers.Steam).

Followed a couple of tutorials for a similar authentication system but using GitHub and re-adapted that code to be used for login with Steam.

Everything is working fine with a couple of logins but after some time it just breaks and wouldn't authenticate properly.

I'm new to Owin and authenticating users with it so any tips on what I should do to debug it or anything related to Owin that I misinterpreted would be helpful.

I don't know how to explain much of the problem, I was trying to debug it but instead of fixing it I just got more confused, here is my code (only relevant parts):

HomeController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
{
    // This is always null after a couple of succuessful authentications
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");

    if(authenticateResult != null)
    {
        var firstOrDefault = authenticateResult.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Issuer == "Steam" && claim.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"));

        var idString = firstOrDefault?.Value;
        var match = _accountIdRegex.Match(idString ?? "");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            var accountID = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var steamID = ulong.Parse(accountID);

            // User Management Code

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("LoginSteam");
}

public ActionResult LoginSteam()
{
    return new ChallengeResult("Steam", Url.Action("Login"));
}
```

ChallengeResult.cs

```
internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

And Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ApplicationNamespace.Startup))]
namespace ApplicationNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static string steamKey = "";

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ExternalCookie");

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                CookieName = ".AspNet.ExternalCookie",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
            });

            var webconfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
#if DEBUG
            steamKey = webconfig.AppSettings.Settings["steamApiKey"].Value;
#else
            steamKey = webconfig.AppSettings.Settings["steamApiKeyRelease"].Value;
#endif

            var options = new SteamAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ApplicationKey = steamKey,
            };

            app.UseSteamAuthentication(options);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I found online, this should be universal and work with any provider, be it Google, Steam, GitHub etc. and it does... for a while... then AuthenticateAsync starts returning null each time and that is where I get confused.
I couldn't find anyone having a similar problem to this online, so I would guess that something is wrong with my code instead of Owin or IIS configuration, what are relevant IIS configs that I should check before testing this again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It worked for almost two years and then it started to fail.

Mine was solved by this solution: https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/catching-the-system-webowin-cookie-monster/

I added

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
```

as first statement in the StartupAuth.cs and the authorization worked again.